# Dashed lines in Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

In this [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6830v2), in e.g. figure 2, what does these dashed lines across the Feynman diagram mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9602280), and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709423). cutting is essentially a shortcut for calculating  complicated diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the most clear reference on the optical theorem and on Cutting rules is chapter 7.3 of Peskin & Schroeder.